# asp.net mvc - how do i reference an asp file inside the View Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have a page inside my asp..net mvc site.  (for some reason it has to be in this directory)

Views/Members/Calendar/admin.asp

i tried going to:

http://www.mySite.com/Views/Members/Calendar/admin.asp

but this doesn't seem to work.

any suggestions on how to have a link to this page?

Comment: Is that a typo? Do you mean ".aspx" or do you really mean ".asp"?

Comment: i mean asp . .. i actually just kept that asp file on another domain and put regular url links to them as i couldn't figure out any other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC blocks all access to any file within the `~/Views` directory. If you want to access any file except `*.aspx` change your `~/Views/web.config` to the following: (from [Haacked - Security Tip: Blocking Access to ASP.NET MVC Views Using Alternative View Engines](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/06/25/aspnetmvc-block-view-access.aspx)):

or remove both `<add ...` if you want to access `*.aspx` files too

For IIS 6:

```
<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*.aspx" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
...
```

For IIS 7:

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
        <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

View has nothing to do with the actual directory / address, in MVC, controller is the one to deal with this.

Suppose you start with the default template of MVC, the address would be:

```
http://site.com/CONTROLLER/ACTION/ID
```

CONTROLLER is the name of the controller class (which under controller directory), ACTION is the method (which return actionresult) within the controller and ID is a string/int that pass as action method parameter.

I think you'd like to have address like:

```
http://mysite.com/Members/Calendar/admin/
```

It doesn't really matter where you put the View or controller, but what you should look at is the routing table within the global.asax. [Routing mvc tutorial](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-23-cs.aspx)

*edit*

In the controller, normally you are going to call

```
return View();
```

At the end of action. View() is actually an overloaded internal method call of the controlelr class which has 8 different usage. The default without parameter will look for the same view name to the controller. All you need to do in order to reference to different view class other than default, is using: [View(IView Class)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460327.aspx). For example, in your code it might be:

```
return View(new PROJECT.Members.Calendar.Admin());
```

Comment: but in this case, at some point i need to point to the asp file in its directory.  from the controller how do i redirect to this view

Comment: Edited. In controller action you can explicitly render other view pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an [IgnoreRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.ignoreroute.aspx) method to the top of your register routes method that ignores this specific URL?  You'll have to edit the web.config in the Views folder to assign this path to the ASP handler because the ~/Views folder gives out 404's by default. The ASP handler should then pick up the request since the MVC handler will ignore it.